# Cant retrieve data and pass it to json

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, pdo

So I'm stuck on this problem for hours upon hours but just cant figure it out. In the frontend Im using jquery datatables but the data I'm trying to pass with ajax either doesnt arrive ("DataTables warning: table id=user_data - Invalid JSON response. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/1") or is empty. I've been using this guide/code as reference http://www.webslesson.info/2017/01/php-pdo-ajax-crud-with-data-tables-and-bootstrap-modals.html. I changed it up a bit but it's still almost exactly the same.

MySQL:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `geschenke` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`name` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
`beschreibung` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
`erreicht` int(15) DEFAULT NULL,
`ziel` int(15) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci 
AUTO_INCREMENT=31 ;
```

dbconfig.php:

```
<?php
$username = 'username';
$password = 'password';
$connection = new PDO( 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=dbname', 
$username, $password );
?>
```

function.php:

```
<?php
function get_total_all_records()
{
include('dbconfig.php');
$statement = $connection->prepare("SELECT * FROM geschenke");
$statement->execute();
$result = $statement->fetchAll();
return $statement->rowCount();
}
?>
```

fetch.php

```
<?php
include('dbconfig.php');
include('function.php');
$query = '';
$output = array();
$query .= "SELECT * FROM geschenke ";
if(isset($_POST["search"]["value"]))
{
$query .= 'WHERE beschreibung LIKE "%'.$_POST["search"]["value"].'%" ';
$query .= 'OR name LIKE "%'.$_POST["search"]["value"].'%" ';
}
if(isset($_POST['order']))
{
$query .= 'ORDER BY '.$_POST['order']['0']['column'].' '.$_POST['order']
['0']['dir'].' ';
}
else
{
$query .= 'ORDER BY id DESC ';
}
if($_POST["length"] != -1)
{
$query .= 'LIMIT ' . $_POST['start'] . ', ' . $_POST['length'];
}
$statement = $connection->prepare($query);
$statement->execute();
$result = $statement->fetchAll();
$data = array();
$filtered_rows = $statement->rowCount();
foreach($result as $row)
{
$image = '';
if($row["name"] != '')
{
$image = '<img src="img/'.$row["name"].'" class="img-thumbnail" width="50" 
height="35" />';
}
else
{
$image = '';
}
$sub_array = array();
$sub_array[] = $image;
$sub_array[] = $row["beschreibung"];
$sub_array[] = $row["erreicht"];
$sub_array[] = $row["ziel"];
$sub_array[] = '<button type="button" name="add_button" 
id="'.$row["name"].'" class="btn btn-warning btn-xs update">Add</button>';
$data[] = $sub_array;
}
$output = array(
"draw"    => intval($_POST["draw"]),
"recordsTotal"  =>  $filtered_rows,
"recordsFiltered" => get_total_all_records(),
"data"   => $data
);
echo json_encode($output);
?>
```

I used print at different parts of the script to see where the mistake is. The array "data" inside the array "output" always comes out as empty. This leads me to believe that somehow fetchAll() isnt getting the data. Another thing I noticed is that if I remove the space behind "geschenke" in

```
$query .= "SELECT * FROM geschenke ";
```

I dont get the error mentioned above, instead a json with recordsTotal=0 , recordsFiltered=28 and data[] is sent.
I tried everything I could, with my limited knowledge, think of but I have no longer any clue why it isnt working.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: $result = $statement->fetchAll();
print_r($result):
check get any data

Comment: @PatrickF, have you print out the $query value to see if it's with correct values? try to execute the printed query directly in mysql directly and see if the result is ok.

Comment: @ShafiqulIslam I get the Array I'm supposed to get! So it seems fetchAll() does work after all.

Comment: @JPKim I printed out the $query and executed it in mysql and it works fine.

Comment: @PatrickF, you are using PDO and PDO don't allow to use quotes in statement . instead,  put a named or unnamed parameter with matched values.

Comment: @PatrickF so do you add your print_r() data in this question so it will easy to solve , if data is big then just first index value

Comment: if you using datatables you don't need all these orders and limits

Comment: I did what @JPKim suggested and it works! At least the ajax call works now, it still throws the invalid json error but the data is listed in the console. I think I can figure it out from here on. Thanks!